# Synonym for 'place' which is not big

Tags: vocabulary

Here are a few new sentences I have written in my diary:

> Our manager was asked to negotiate with the retailing shops' managers and signed the agreements with them. These retailing shops will have to keep our cakes in good condition in their window cabinets. Because the cakes will occupy some of the **places** in their window cabinets, we need to pay each shop more than a thousand dollars monthly.

Because the word **place** sounds like it is very big in size, I want to replace it with some better word, but my vocabulary is weak.

Comment: To this native US English speaker (and I think most native English speakers) *place* does not imply anything about size.

Comment: The word "place" doesn't necessarily refer to a physical location: à la "putting someone in their place".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Baked goods are typically arranged inside glass display cases. The space is usually referred to as **shelf space**.

[This article](http://www.foodservicewarehouse.com/blog/how-to-display-your-bakery-items/)  might give you some vocabulary.

And [this one](http://bizshifts-trends.com/2014/05/18/war-retail-shelf-space-battle-shelf-placement-fight-low-slotting-fees-position-mindshare/) too.

Comment: I thought of this one, too. Or even just space, optionally with a specific amount as in, "...the cakes will occupy (a small amount of) space in their window cabinets".

Answer (score 6):

The first word that comes to my mind is "spot".

Comment: Could you give one or two example sentences on how to use Spot, please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Retail uses the phrase 'display spaces' for any type of area where a product is being displayed for promotional purposes.

Answer (score 3):

You can always say

> Because the cakes will occupy *a (small) part* of their window cabinets

But *place* has so many different meanings, and the sentence already implies there are multiple places in the window cabinet, that I would not expect those places to be big in size.

Answer (score 1):

positions, slots, spots, locations...

I think position is used commonly in a retail or advertising context.

Comment: Could you explain why you'd choose any of these phrases and back them up with sources, dictionary definitions etc.? Unreferenced claims may be challenged and removed.

Answer (score 0):

While afraid I might be a bit out of context, I'm wondering if it ia really the word "place" that is causing the problem. With that in mind, my eyes quickly jumped to "occupy", which does give an air of being a "negative" word, if the idea of "not taking space" is the ultimate goal. Based on these assumptions, a complete re-engineering of the passage might be needed. An idea is:

These retailing shops will have to keep our cakes in good condition in their window cabinets. We will pay each shop a sum that exceeds thousand dollars monthly for their services in displaying the cakes in their window cabinets.

(And now the issue of how much space they take was bypassed, because the word 'services' tend to shift the mind towards the actual placing of cakes instead of them just sitting there.)

However, further investigation of the situation, reminds me of the matter of "borrowing". Sometimes we tend to use expressions that come from our mother tongues in other languages, where they don't carry the same (or worse, sometimes the complete opposite) meaning, or connotation. If we are talking of a business situation, it's then important to allocate for that possibility where words in English being read by a non-native might carry connotations that would not be taken by their value as perceived by native speakers, but by how the psyche of the reader was shaped by the perception of these words in their languages. As an example - or 2 :)

Portuguese: "a place" (in the context of the paragraph) would hint at that place belonging to something else.

Arabic: "a place" (again in the context of the paragraph) carries an idea of unavailability.

But I have been wrong before ;)